# which sql server edition is good for practice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, log-shipping, mirroring

Which SQL Server (free/trail) would be good to install, which requires minimum resource and have maximum features. I mean, I can practice mirroring,logshipping and replication. I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but confuse with enterprise and standard edition.

Comment: See the [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143506.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 180 day evaluation version from Microsoft is Enterprise Edition.  AFAIK there is no ability to "trial" Standard edition from Microsoft outside of a licensing agreement you might have.

From the point of view of overhead between editions, there's negligible difference.

If you want something longer than 180 days, get the developer edition as its feature complete compared to Enterprise but only [$50 from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007RFXQAM)

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server Editions**
SQL Server 2008 is available in the following editions:

1. Enterprise Designed for the largest organizations and those needing to leverage the
   full power of the SQL Server 2008 platform.
2. Standard Designed for small and midsized organizations that do not need all the
   capabilities available in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.
3. Workgroup Suitable for small departmental projects with a limited set of features.
4. Express A freely redistributable version of SQL Server that is designed to handle
   the needs of embedded applications as well as the basic data storage needs for
   server-based applications, such as Web applications with a small number of users.
5. Compact Designed as an embedded database.
6. Developer Designed for use by developers in creating SQL Server applications.
   SQL Server 2008 Developer has all the features and capabilities as SQL Server 2008
   Enterprise, except that it is not allowed to be used in a production environment.
7. Evaluation Designed to allow organizations to evaluate SQL Server 2008. SQL Server
   2008 Evaluation has all the features and capabilities as SQL Server 2008 Enterprise,
   except that it is not allowed to be used in a production environment and it expires
   after 180 days.

[image: hardware]
[image: engine support1]
[image: engine support2]

Reference: Microsoft SQL Server Implementation and Maintenance (Exam 70-432)